# Missing type or namespace after installing MRTK Azure Spatial Anchor packet

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-sharing-01) tutorial from Microsoft in order to setup a multi-users exeperience between an Hololens and an Android app.

**The Issue**
The issue is that after installing PUN-2 + `MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.7.2` + `MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.MultiUserCapabilities.2.7.2` as stated in the tutorial I still end up with the following error :

```
Assets\MRTK.Tutorials.MultiUserCapabilities\Scripts\SharingModuleScript.cs(7,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AnchorModuleScript' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**What I've tried**
According to a similar post I tried to add the `MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.7.2` packet since it should be the missing piece but I ended up with even more missing types or names spaces like `Azur` or `SpatialAnchorManager` and other ones.

**Config**
I use Unity 2019.4.36f1 with MRTK 2.8.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, this project requires the following asset packages, you can try. It should be noted that for this project, the official document recommends using Unity 2020 LTS and MRTK 2.7.2. And for Mixed Reality development, the official currently recommends using Unity 2020.3 LTS, please refer to [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version).

1. MRTK/Mixed Reality Toolkit Foundation
2. MRTK/Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin
3. MRTK/Azure Spatial Anchors SDK Core
4. MRTK/Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for Windows
5. [MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.MultiUserCapabilities.2.7.2.unitypackage](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/multi-user-capabilities-v2.7.2/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.MultiUserCapabilities.2.7.2.unitypackage)
6. [MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.7.2.unitypackage](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/getting-started-v2.7.2/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.7.2.unitypackage)
7. [MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.7.2.unitypackage](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/download/azure-spatial-anchors-v2.7.2/MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.7.2.unitypackage)
8. PUN 2 - FREE

Comment: Thank you for testing out my issue, I tried dto add the `AzureSpatialAnchors.2.7.2...` but I get the following error now `CS1061: 'IntPtr' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' `. I'll try to downgrade my MRKT version but I think it shouldn't be an issue